# Grails not able to add an object property. How would this be achieved?

Tags: model-view-controller, grails, groovy, controller, crud

```grail
Class A {
   String nameA 
   B b
}

Class B {
   String nameB
}
```

So within my controller right now I have: `def temp = AService.get(id)` and I want to add a `B` object to temp.

I have seen things like: `temp.addToB({b params})` but it did not work for me. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what makes you think, that this would work?

Answer (score 2):

> I have seen things like temp.addToB({b params}) but I have had not
> success.

If you have a reference to an instance of `A` and you want to initialize the `b` property in that instance, you can use Groovy's property assignment support to do that.

```
A someA = new A()
someA.b = new B()
```

```
A someA = aService.get(id)
someA.b = new B()
```

```
A someA = aService.get(id)
someA.b = bService.get(someOtherId)
```

Etc.